# How to resolve Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, log4net

Hello I am working on one project which I am setting up the Log4Net settings with the help of Linq . But when I assign a function to that Lambda Expression it gives me error.

```
ICollection MyConfiguration.ConfigureLog4Net(string processName)
      {
          //my custom code
          return log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4netConfigElement);
      }
```

My calling code :

```
NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(() => MyConfiguration.ConfigureLog4Net("myLog")); // error here
```

Over here I get the error:

> Cannot convert Lambda Expression to type NserviceBus.Configure because it is not a delegate type

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this ?

Comment: what is the signature of `Log4Net(?)`?

Comment: There are 4 overloads - empty, Action,
(this Configure config),
(configure, appender)

Comment: What about if using: `Log4Net(() => { MyConfiguration.. })`? Note the braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think this works:

```
NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net((Action)(() => MyConfiguration.ConfigureLog4Net("myLog")));
```

or

```
NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(new Action(() => MyConfiguration.ConfigureLog4Net("myLog")));
```